# Hair disappears in particle edit mode

Tags: hair

once ive got my hair all sorted i go to particle edit mode to position it and stuff but its all suddenly gone and all i see is the model the hair is on??

anyone help??[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.8, to see the hair in *Particle Edit* mode you need to have *overlays* switched on.

To see the children in *Particle Edit* mode, open the tool bar (press N) and in the *Tool* tab there is *Options*. In that tab is *Viewport Display* where *Children* needs to be switched on.

The *Path Steps* will display less/more of the children hair length.